# PDF Generation with Ruby on Rails 6.0 and Heroku

Tags: heroku, pdf-generation, ruby-on-rails-6, pdfkit, wicked-pdf

I am stucked with pdf generation in a Ruby on Rails 6.0 (Ruby v2.7.1) website on HEROKU.

**The goal**: generate on the run a pdf photo gallery including a list of pictures. The gallery is from an external service and it is imported by API. The PDF should include 1 or 2 images per page and may be very long (up to 30/40pages). There should be multiple users to serve with the pdfs, and the request could be more than 10 per minute. This is  fully functioning on other websites.

**What I have tried**: I tried several ways to generate PDFs with Rails, using gems like wicked_pdf, pdf_kit (both based on wkhtmltopdf) or grover (based on puppeteer).
When I'm in localhost I can download the pdf with good style, it is very slow, but I get them, but i got very big issues in production.

**the issues**:

1. In production environment (Heroku) my slug size is Enormous (approx 400 Megabyte) due to wkhtmltopdf or puppeteer that occupies approx 250Mb. This seems to heavily impact on memory usage of the server.
2. The request to create PDFs are really slow, more than 20 sec and it often goes to timeout.
3. After the same request I see an big increase of memory usage. I expect to go out of memory after a few requests.
4. I got the same issues even I create smaller pdfs, of only a few pages

I've tried several versions of standard code provided by the docs of and all of them generates the pdf, but the performance issues are blocking the usage of them in production. What should be useful is to have some guidelines to understand how to proceed.

**my questions**:

- The usage of a background job may solve timeout issues? but I expect that cannot solve the very long creation time of the pdfs.
- Is it a good idea to use more workers or jobs on Heroku? do this may increase the performance of PDF creation?
- Any suggestion on other ways to proceed or using lighter libraries or services?
- I can think to generate only one time the pdf and save it on S3, but the data is created on another server and I get that through API and I cannot check for any modification of that

I got the information from the old developers of the same website that the same exact data I need was served in a few seconds using the chain XML - XSLFO - PDF through FOP on .net and apache, totally incompatible with Rails and Heroku.

here below I'm posting one version of my code to generate the pdf with **wicked_pdf gem**, but it is something that I clearly have to update.

```
def book_pdf
    # code to generate the picture list and title of the gallery #

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.pdf do
            render  pdf:            @model_name.parameterize,
                    orientation:    "Landscape", 
                    page_size: 'A4',
                    show_as_html:  false,
                    disposition: 'attachment',
                    header: { :html => { :template => 'pdf/book_header.pdf.erb' } },
                    footer: { :html => { :template => 'pdf/book_footer.pdf.erb' } },
                    quality: 50, 
                    zoom: Rails.env.production? ? 0.81 : 1.00, 
                    layout: "pdf.html"
             
        end
    end
end

WickedPdf.config = {
   layout: 'pdf.html.erb',
   print_media_type: true,
   page_size: 'A4',
   encoding: 'utf-8',
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- If the same pdf is going to be served to several people, and the pdf itself won't change often, it might be better to generate it once and store it in S3, with a DB record in your application having the URL stored with some identifying parameters
- If several people are asking for the same pdf (no data change) and it is in S3 already (you can identify from your DB record), you can just serve it without fresh generation
- Moving PDF generation to a background worker in sidekiq will really free up the web-application for actual http requests and prevent your current timeout issues
- Having more workers might improve performance for concurrently occurring pdf requests, but the time taken for each pdf generation (within a worker) will not improve
- Since you say the pdf is only images, and you don't know when the other server has made changes, maybe you can have a polling job in the background trying to find out **when the data has changed to proactively generate a new pdf** and store it on S3 even before someone asks for it.
- When the pdf is generating in the background, if the DB record has the identifying tags for that pdf and some people are asking for it (http requests) you can implement some sort of polling or websocket flow where the user’s browser constantly asks and waits for the server to say that the pdf is ready.